# Javascript inhertiance in anonymous functions

Tags: javascript

I have the following code I am trying to run, I get an error at the last line. From my understanding x's prototype chain looks good. What am I missing here

```
var Child = (function(){

  function Parent(){
    this.name ="parent";
    this.parentHello = function(){
      console.log("parent hello "+this.name);
    };
  }

  return function(){
    function Bridge(){

    }
    Bridge.prototype = new Parent();    
    this.constructor.prototype = new Bridge();    
    this.hello = function(){
        console.log('hello');
    };
  };
})();

var x = new Child();


console.log(x.constructor);
console.log(x.constructor.prototype);
x.hello();
x.constructor.prototype.parentHello();  // This works
x.parentHello();  // TypeError: x.parentHello is not a function
```

This is modeled after an existing code, I cannot change the structure of it. I modified the original a little bit to post as question.

Comment: is there a reason you have your structure like that? why?

Comment: Just a side note: You *are* aware that JavaScript has a `class` and an `extends` keyword, aren't you?

Comment: This is the most confusing way I've ever seen to write objects and do inheritance.  It is a no wonder that something does not work properly.  The answer is to write inheritance in a normal, non-confusing way that you can easily pull directly from a working example.

Comment: "_I get an error_" Mind telling us what it is....?

Comment: `Child` doesnt have a `parentHello` function, it only has a `Parent` function. when you do `this.parentHello = function(){...` you're doing it in the definition of `Parent` not the instance of `Child`. When you instantiate the `Parent`, you're not doing it in place of `Child`, you're doing it in `Bridge.prototype`

Comment: Maybe try defining it before you try to run it. Put `this.parentHello = Bridge.prototype.parentHello;` inside your `return function(){`

Comment: @jfriend00: The absolutely most confusing way you've seen to do inheritance?  You obviously have not worked with some of the junior developers at my company!  This barely makes middle of the pack.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvotes either.  The code is pretty awful, IMHO, but the question itself shows some effort and makes it easy to replicate and to test.

Comment: I really know other ways to achieve this inheritance in a simple way. This is from an existing code and I cannot major changes.. At this point I am really interested to know the reason why it wouldn't work. I think it has all links set properly as per lang spec.

Comment: Updated my answer below with a more complete explanation of why this fails.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - The point is that confusing code should be rewritten to not be confusing rather than just trying to patch it to work and leave it confusing.  The downvotes are likely because this is a bad way to do inheritance and thus not really worth trying to patch it back together.

Comment: @jfriend00: I guess I read it more literally as written: _Why doesn't this work?_  rather than _Help me fix it_.  I did offer a fix, but with the intent of showing what was wrong along the way.  I updated my answer to make the actual issues more clear.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - So, if a junior developer in your company comes to you with this question, how do you respond?  Do you offer the answer you did below?  Or do you coach them on a much cleaner way to do inheritance?  That's my point.  The best answer here (in my opinion) is to teach how to do clean inheritance, not how to patch a messy design not to have an error.  I don't patch confusing code.  I first make the code not be confusing, then fix any remaining problems, thus making things a lot more maintainable and probably preventing several future bugs.

Comment: @jfriend00 I would answer their question first of why it doesn't work, and then show them a better way to do it. Anything less creates a generation of cargo-cult followers. Big Bird rules!

Comment: @jfriend00, Well, a junior developer does not get to tell me, "I cannot change the structure of it."  :-)  But yes, I do treat these as learning experiences (hopefully a little more interactively than can be done in SO), but starting with _What's wrong?_ and _How do we patch this?_ before moving to _How do we do this better?_ and eventually _What is really the best way to do this?_  But I would have no problem with a downvote on my answer based on your notions, I just don't think the **question** deserves them.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - This question only asks what's wrong with the existing code.  It does not describe what the goal of the code is.  It's such an odd design pattern and implemented wrongly to boot, that it is not clear what the actual intent of the code is.  We are apparently supposed to guess that.  As such, it's a poor question.  Good questions describe the goal and good answers offer the best ways to achieve that goal, regardless of the OP's original coding direction.  "Can't change the structure" is just hogwash.  It's bad code - it should be changed.

Comment: Telling us that a bad structure can't be changed reminds me of an old adage in coding: "There's never enough time to do it right the first time, but always enough time to do it over several times later when it has to be redone in order to actually work".  Do it right the first time, even if it takes a bit longer because it will pay major dividends down the road when you have a more solid code foundation to build upon.

Comment: @jfriend00: Perhaps you're right.  The code structure was horrid.  But it seemed quite clear to me from the start what the goal was so it was easy enough to show minor modifications that would reach that goal.  Maybe this does not serve useful pedagogical purposes.  Although I've been around SO a while now, you're clearly much more experienced here.  Would you suggest editing my answer to remove the code changes, leaving only the _why it fails_ explanation?

Comment: @ScottSauyet - The best answers show the best way to solve the problem and describe it well.  I have no problem with you explaining what went wrong with the OP's code, but it would be a more complete answer if you showed the better and more common methods of doing inheritance using the appropriate tools (both ES6 syntax and the ES5 `Object.create()` method).

Comment: @jfriend00: ok, I don't think I'll change this answer, since the OP described in the comments an understanding of better techniques, and those techniques are clearly documented all around SO, but I will try to keep it in mind for future answers.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - I wrote my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Why the original doesn't work.  You've asked in the comments to the question why it doesn't work.  I'm not going to dig up the actual specifications for this for you, but the explanation is straightforward.

You do this:

```
this.constructor.prototype = new Bridge();
```

*inside* the constructor function.  That's too late.  When the JS Engine creates an object with `new` it looks to the constructor function you're calling, creates a new empty object, then assigns the prototype of that object from the constructor's prototype.  Then it applies the function in the context of this newly created object.  Inside there, you reassign the prototype of the constructor, but it's too late.

It's easy to see that this is the issue by just doing this:

```
var x = new Child();
x.parentHello(); // throws an exception
var y = new Child(); // gets the updated prototype
y.parentHello(); // works as expected
```

But the big question is *why* you would want to reassign the prototype from within the constructor.  It is an extremely confusing notion, even if it were to work properly.

---

We now return you to your originally scheduled **answer**.

---

The reason this doesn't work is that you're confusing levels, and trying to do something inside a constructor function that really should be done outside of it.  Below is what I think of as the minimal modification of your code to make it work.  It is not how I would suggest actually writing this, but it's a starting place for discussion:

```
var Child = (function(){

  function Parent(){
    this.name ="parent";
    this.parentHello = function(){
      console.log("parent hello "+this.name);
    };
  }

  function Child() {
    this.hello = function(){
      console.log('hello');
    };
  }

  function Bridge(){}
  Bridge.prototype = new Parent();    
  Child.prototype = new Bridge();
  Child.prototype.constructor = Parent;
  return Child;
})(); 

var x = new Child();

x.hello(); //=> logs "hello"
x.parentHello(); //=> logs "parent hello parent"
```

Now that last block really should become an `inherit` function or some such:

```
var inherit = function(Parent, Child) {
  function Bridge(){}
  Bridge.prototype = new Parent();    
  Child.prototype = new Bridge();
  Child.prototype.constructor = Parent;
  return Child;
}

var Child = (function(){

  function Parent(){
    this.name ="parent";
    this.parentHello = function(){
      console.log("parent hello "+this.name);
    };
  }

  function Child() {
    this.hello = function(){
      console.log('hello');
    };
  }

  return inherit(Parent, Child);
})();
```

Often these days, these things are handled in one of two different ways, though.  This version is pretty old-school.  Instead now, if you're using es6, there is a `class` syntax that does pretty much the equivalent of this.  And if not, techniques using `Object.create` are very common.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Now I understand why it wouldn't work. Thanks for explaining that doing it inside the function is too late.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to attempt to both explain what was wrong with your code and show a better way to achieve the same inheritance you have now.

**Analysis of your code:**

1. `Child` is a constructor function.
2. In a private scope of that function is the `Parent()` constructor
3. Calling the `Child` function with `new` attepts to return a new object that initializes the `Bridge` constructor and prototype and then attempts to set the constructor of the current object's prototype to `new Bridge()`.
4. I'm guessing here since you don't explicitly describe what you're trying to accomplish, but it looks like maybe you're trying to create two levels of inheritance where Parent is the base, then Bridge derives from Parent, then Child derives from Bridge.
5. But, you can't be setting the prototype for `Child` in the constructor of `Child`.  That's too late to be setting it because the first `Child` object has already been created.
6. So, when you do `x = new Child();`, x will just be a Child object without inheriting from Bridge.  Thus, there is no `.parentHello()` method on it.
7. When you create new objects with inheritance, you also need to call the inherited constructors so they can properly initialize their instances.

**Fixing the code:**

1. Since the inheritance structure here is fixed and completely known ahead of time, there is no reason to try to do this dynamically.  It should be assigned once at the time the Child IIFE runs, not inside the Child constructor.  This will both fix timing issues and make the code run properly.
2. Further, it's 2016, so we should be using `Object.create()` to create prototypes, not `new`.
3. And, objects needs to call the constructors of the things they inherit from.

Here's what I would suggest (you can run this snippet and look in the debug console):

```js
var Child = (function(){

  // define base class
  function Parent(){
    this.name ="parent";
    this.parentHello = function(){
      console.log("parent hello "+this.name);
    };
  }
  Parent.prototype.constructor = Parent;
  
  // define Bridge which inherits from Parent
  function Bridge() {
      // call parent constructor
      Parent.call(this);
  }
  Bridge.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);    
  Bridge.prototype.bridgeHello = function() {
      console.log("bridge hello");
  }
  Bridge.prototype.constructor = Bridge;

  function Child() {
      // call parent constructor
      Bridge.call(this);
      this.hello = function(){
        console.log('hello');
      };
  }
  Child.prototype = Object.create(Bridge.prototype);
  Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
  
  return Child;
})();

var x = new Child();

console.log(x);
console.log(x.constructor);
x.hello();
x.bridgeHello();
x.parentHello();
```

And, here's a similar implementation using the [more modern ES6 `class` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) (you can run this snippet in a browser that supports ES6 classes such as Chrome, Firefox or Edge):

```js
"use strict";

var Child = (function(){

  // base class
  class Parent {
    constructor() {
       this.name = "parent";
    }
    parentHello() {
       console.log("parent hello "+this.name);
    }
  }

  // define Bridge which inherits from Parent
  class Bridge extends Parent {
    constructor() {
       super();
       this.name = "bridge";
    }
    bridgeHello() {
        console.log("bridge hello");
    }
  }
  
  class Child extends Bridge {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.name = "child";
    }
    hello() {
      console.log('hello');
    }
  }

  return Child;
})();

var x = new Child();

console.log(x);
console.log(x.constructor);
x.hello();
x.bridgeHello();
x.parentHello();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!